# Linq Query is taking long time

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Following is taking to long -

```
using (var db = new Agreements_DBEntities())
{

    bool isProfileExist = (from ua in db.UserAgreementDetails
                                     where ua.uID == uID &&
                                           ua.uMailId == uMailId &&
                                           ua.uType == uType &&
                                           ua.UProfile.HasValue && ua.UProfile.Value
                                     select true).Any();
}
```

above line `bool isProfileExist` is taking too long....what is wrong in it?

Comment: What does it mean 'too long'? How 'long' is acceptable? **What is the generated SQL query?** Do you have your indexes in place? What does the execution plan on SQL Server side look like? Is it a 'cold' query, or has it been already executed at least once?

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you could  remove the `where` clause and directly use `Any` (I'm not sure how the IQueryable provider will optimize the Linq) and how you are benchmarking it but:

```
db.UserAgreementDetails.Any(ua => ua.uID == uID &&
                                           ua.uMailId == uMailId &&
                                           ua.uType == uType &&
                                           ua.UProfile.HasValue && ua.UProfile.Value);
```

Even then, how many rows do you have in the db? Is it the first time the query executed, etc..?

Comment: Won't that generate same query?

Comment: @wudzik Depends on the provider I think

Comment: And perhaps the `Any` removes selection and projection he had before. But I can't test it right now.

Comment: Probably :) Worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to check the actual query produced. SQLServer Profiler is great for this, and other databases have other query logging approaches.

There may be better SQL produced if we simplify out the unnecessary bits of your query to:

```
bool isProfileExist = db.UserAgreementDetails.Any(
    ua => ua.uID == uID &&
    ua.uMailId == uMailId &&
    ua.uType == uType &&
    ua.UProfile.HasValue &&
    ua.UProfile.Value);
```

I'd imagine this would produce pretty much the same code, but it might not, and it's worth trying if the query provider gave something strange.

After that, I would guess (but can't know for sure) that the main culprit is in fact the database server. Check that you have an index or set of indices that make this query execute quickly.

The idea index would probably be one that covered the columns corresponding to `uID`, `uMailId`, `uType` and `UProfile`, or one including some of those and "having" the others. However, one needs to not consider this query in isolation, so you might decide that separate indices on them, or an index just covering some would do: In particular, if there would only ever be a small number of rows with the same `uID`, then an index just on that should do the job, without adding as much cost to insert, and also benefiting a larger number of other queries.